# keyboard is not getting dismissed on UITextField

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitextfield

This may sound a newbie question, however I'm new to iOS dev.

Platform : iPad

I have a UITableView with UITextField, let say they are two.
When pressing on the first one virtual keyboard should appear, but when user tapps on the second UITextField the virtual keyboard should be hidden and data picker view should be displayed.

So here it is, how I did it.

```
-(void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField.tag == PICKER_VIEW_TAG) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    } else {
        ...
    }
}

-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField.tag != PICKER_VIEW_TAG) {
        ...
    }
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField.tag == PICKER_VIEW_TAG) {
        [self countriesPickerView];
    }
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField.tag == PICKER_VIEW_TAG) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    } else {
        ... 
    }
    return YES;
}
```

So now the question, when I click for the first time on the first UITextField it displays keyboard, but when I switch to second one it does not hide it. Why ? and how to solve this ?

UPDATE : The corresponding textField is not getting selected but i.e. the resign takes place, right ? but the keyboard is not hidden ... why this happens ?

Comment: Have you set the delegate of your texfields and made sure the delegate methods are being called? `textfield.delegate = self;`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your textFieldShouldReturn. If you want it to complete the action, allow it to return while resigning the first responder.

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
```

Comment: Updated code still the same effect, after making keyboard to appear on the fist UITextField, when I click on the second the keyboard is not getting hidden.

Comment: I'm assuming you have your UITextFieldDelegate added in your header file so it knows to call these overridden methods?

Comment: sure, I've added it into header

Comment: The thing is I want the keyboard to be hidden when I click on a specific UITextField it does not matter should return what returns...

Comment: Try resigning it in your shouldBeginEditing. if (textField == yourTextField) [yourTextField resignFirstResponder];

Comment: Objects are not supposed to be compared like that ... However I've tried also resigning textFeild in shouldBeginEditing .. yet the smae problem ...

Answer (score 1):

Set the `inputView` property on `UITextField` to display views other than keyboard to receive input. In this case, you would set the text field's `inputView` to be an instance of `UIDatePicker`. The picker will be displayed with the same keyboard animation automatically and you get to delete a bunch of code. Win/win.